# php assigning element name property based on database record value

Tags: php

Im trying to assign the value from a database record called poolid to the name property of a radio button element.

Here is what I tried, needless to say it is not working, and it gives me a syntax error. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Please keep in mind I am very new to PHP so I am looking for the simplest way. Thanks

```
echo'<td><input type="radio" name="'$row['poolid']"</td>';
```

Comment: Seeing that you mix up a lot of a HTML there, read up on HEREDOC strings even - for readability.

Comment: Good question, marilee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing dots, and the last string is missing the end of the `input` element, and it also has mismatched quote characters.

```
echo'<td><input type="radio" name="'.$row['poolid'].'"></td>';
```

In PHP you need to use the dot character, `.`, to glue stuff together. If you know Javascript then the dot is like the plus character, `+` (except it does not do addition).

Gluing together values, like this, is called *concatenation*. The dot is called the *concatenation operator*.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing dots and single quote, and input end... or put variables in double quotes:

```
echo'<td><input type="radio" name="'.$row['poolid'].'" /></td>';
```

Or

```
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='{$row['poolid']}' /></td>";
```